# C# aspx image upload using angular

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angularjs

I am using aspx page with angular js.
I've used angular and c# webmethod file upload.

I've tried to upload the image like used in web api.

> When using web api, the image is uploaded successfully. When I try
>   with aspx, the webmethod is not hitting, but the result is coming with
>   the status success and also with the html page.

'

> C# server side code didn't hit anyway.

**The following is my Angular code which is working with Web api**

```
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                var form = new FormData();
                if (file)
                    form.append("image", file);

                var url = "Page.aspx/UploadImage";

                xhr.open("Post", url, true);
                xhr.onload = function () {
                    if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 300) {
                        resolve(xhr.response);
                    } else {
                        reject(xhr.statusText);
                    }
                };
                xhr.onerror = function () {
                    reject(xhr.statusText);
                };

                xhr.send(form);
            });
```

**C#:**

```
public static string UploadImage()
        {
 if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.AllKeys.Any())
                {
                    httpPostedFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["image"];

                    if (Path.GetExtension(httpPostedFile.FileName) == "" || !allowedImageTypes.Contains(Path.GetExtension(httpPostedFile.FileName), StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                        BLErrorHandler.ApplicationError("Invalid image type", ValidationError.ERR28);


                }
}
```

Comment: Well, one way for that to happen is if `HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.AllKeys` is empty. Have you checked that?

Comment: If you debug your server code maybe another method is handling the request, have you debugged your server to check for that?

Comment: He mentioned earlier that It doesn't hit server

Comment: @JeevaSusej: If it doesn't hit the server, it's very unlikely that he would get a response, therefore the logic is faulty

Comment: Oh yes. You are right. It might be hit the server, but not hitting the specified method.